# Seperate Business Classes or Entity Classes generated by Linq to SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I have to start a project in which backed database is SQL Server and i am using .Net framework 3.5.

I decided to Use LINQ to SQL for data access layer. Shall I write separate classes to Use for Business layer and Presentation layer or I use auto generated entity classes by LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Entity Framework Code First, but the following concept is the same (*for non-trivial projects*):

I always keep my DAL classes out of my actual business layers. That way it lessens the impact of DB changes on your application. I never use DAL classes anywhere other than my DAL project.

My current project makes use of DDD, any the layout is similar to the following (massively simplified):

```
MainApp                    
MainApp.Domain             
   |...IRepositories
   |...AggregrateX
   |...AggregrateY
MainApp.Dal            
   |...Models
   |...Repositories
```

- MainApp - Can see Domain, but not DAL
- MainApp.Dal - Can see Domain, but not
  MainApp

The DAL repository methods make use of AutoMapper:

```
public Customer Get(int customerId)
{
    using (var context = GetContext())
    {
        var entity = context.Customers.Where(x=> 
            x.CustomerId == customerId).Single();

        return Mapper.Map<DtoCustomer, Customer>(entity);
    }
}

public void Save(Customer customer)
{
    using (var context = GetContext())
    {
        var entity = context.Customers.Where(x=> 
            x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId).Single();

        Mapper.Map(customer, entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Thereby allowing total separation between my business classes and my actual DAL/DTO objects. It, in theory, allows the entire backend to be changed without affecting any of the business logic. What I've not shown is that I then also ensure Domain/Business objects are never seen by the presentation layer as I map to and from Input/View Models instead via a facade.

Basically, what I'm left with is a domain layer that contains all business logic that doesn't care what's using it or how it's populated or how it's persisted, and a DAL layer who's sole purpose is the population and persistence of my domain/business classes.

***However, this only really makes sense for large projects. I would just use the DAL classes on trivial/small projects.***

Comment: I agree. Size does matter. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what we did. We are using L2S for our next generation manufacturing applications. We're a $2.5B global solar manufacturing company. We have two sets of entities. We have our L2S entities which we strictly use in our 'back-end'. We then have a much lighter set of application / domain entities that are used in our client applications and passed back and forth to our back-end.

In many cases, we'll use views that model our domain entities and then bring the view into our L2S model, as a read-only table. This allows us to have 'domain' entities and we're able to use L2S to query the respective views to hydrate these entities.

Works very well for us.

Comment: Are your 'client applications' web applications, or smart clients such as Win Forms or Silverlight?

Comment: @Steven - We have all three. Web apps, Win forms and a couple Silverlight apps.